# Find the asymptotes of $y=\log(4-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Find the asymptotes of $y=\log(4-x^2)$

Please help me to solve the problem.

If asymptote is in the form $y=mx+c$

$$m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{y}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(4-x^2)}{x}=$$

$c=\lim_{x\to\infty}(y-mx)=$

Comment: Have you tried to plot this function? What is the domain of this function?

Comment: To find $m$, it's better to first differentiate your function and take $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @angryavian I have ploted but I need a mathematical solution. Please help. Domain: $-2\leq x\leq 2$

Comment: @user1942348 What happens as $x \to 2$ and as $x \to -2$?

Comment: y becomes undefined

Comment: @angryavian Please suggest

Comment: If the function is defined on a bounded interval, there are no asymptotes at $x = \pm \infty$ since $y$ isn't defined near there. What other kinds of asymptotes are possible?

Comment: It is true that  there are no asymptotes at $x = \pm \infty$. Question is whether there are asymptotes at $x=\pm 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function has an asymptote of the form $y =  mx + b$ if 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x) - (mx + b)| = 0$$
or 
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} |f(x) - (mx + b)| = 0$$
If $m = 0$, the asymptote is horizontal.  Otherwise, it is oblique.

However, the domain of $f(x) = \log (4 - x^2)$ is $(-2, 2)$ since we require that the argument of the logarithm be positive, which implies 
\begin{align*}
4 - x^2 & > 0\\
4 & > x^2\\
2 & > |x|
\end{align*}
Thus, $|x|$ cannot approach infinity, so the function has neither a horizontal nor an oblique asymptote.

Observe that 
$$\lim_{x \to 2^-} (4 - x^2) = 0$$
and that 
$$\lim_{x \to -2^+} (4 - x^2) = 0$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x \to 2^-} \log(4 - x^2) = -\infty$$
and 
$$\lim_{x \to -2^+} \log(4 - x^2) = -\infty$$
Thus, $f(x) = \log(4 - x^2)$ has vertical asymptotes at $x = 2$ and $x = -2$.

A graph of $f$ is shown below for base $e$.  If you meant base $10$, multiply each $y$-coordinate of the graph by 
$$\frac{\log_e x}{\log_e 10}$$
Note that the choice of base does not affect the location of the vertical asymptotes.

[image: graph_of_logarithmic_function]